React native application crashes when i trigger an action of localPushNotification
i hope you are fine. I encounter a problem with my ReactNative application. I use react-native-push-notification. When I trigger the push notification, it works. But when i click on an action of push notification, my application crashes without information in the log. And in the configuration of the pushNotfication, the fonction onAction is not executed after or before crashing of application, when i click on an action. Can you help me please! Thank you
here my configuration of pushNotification
static configurePushNotification = () => {
    PushNotification.configure({
        onRegister: function (token) {
            console.log('TOKEN:', token);
        },

        onNotification: function (notification) {
            console.log('NOTIFICATION:', notification);
        },
        onAction: function (notification) {
            if (notification.action?.toLowerCase() === 'Ouvrir'.toLocaleLowerCase()) {
                NavigationUtils.currentNavigation.navigate('Notification')
            }
            else if (notification.action?.toLowerCase() === 'Fermer'.toLocaleLowerCase()) {
                console.log(notification.userInteraction.valueOf());
            }
            console.log(notification.action);
        },
        onRegistrationError: function (err) {
            console.error(err.message, err);
        },

        permissions: {
            alert: true,
            badge: true,
            sound: true,
        },
        popInitialNotification: true,
        requestPermissions: Platform.OS === 'ios',
    });
};

here my push notification calling
            PushNotification.localNotification({
                channelId: 'channel-id',
                title: data.titre,
                message: data.message,
                actions: ['Ouvrir', 'Fermer'],
                vibrate: true,
            });

